# go back / return to / again

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which is correct? I am going to write an example

If we want our country to be developed we have to go back to produce....
If we want our country to be developed we have to produce....again...

If we want our country to be developed we have to return to producing....

I am not sure when use go back / again / return when it comes to talking about something you used to do before.

Answer (score -1):

The second one is the correct one out of the three.
You could also write something along the lines of:

> we need to start producing ... again

.

> we need to begin production of ... again

But "we want our country to be developed" is also somewhat incorrect.

> If we want to see our country develop

or

> If we want to see our country continue to develop

would be somewhat better.